# Where can I download Zip version of Lucene.NET 2.9.1 / 2.9.2

Tags: lucene.net

I m looking for the link to download the latest version of Lucene.Net 2.9.1/.2, but I can see only the src. Can anyone tell me where can I find the zipped version of  Lucene.NET 2.9.1 / 2.9.2
Thanks
Ranga

Answer (score 2):

you can download it here
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/lucene.net/site/download/

click on the first
download --> folder "src" --> folder "lucene.net"--> folder "bin" -->folder "realease" --> your DLL :)

Edit:
you're right, i just searched for a while, and finally read this on  http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/

-23 April 2007 - Released Lucene.Net 2.0 "final" build 004 on SVN and as ZIP.

ok Version 2.0 avaiabil as SVN and ZIP
but after that there is no Version as ZIP Version availabil

-17 Feburary 2010 - "Tag" Released Lucene.Net 2.9.1 "final" build 002 on SVN.

--> just SVN
(https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/lucene.net/tags/Lucene.Net_2_9_1/)

--> there is no ZIP Version after lucene.net 2.0

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record and for all you lazy ones ;)

you can download Lucene.Net.dll from

http://code.google.com/p/subtext/source/browse/trunk/src/Dependencies/?r=4047

Comment: any place to download latest src code zip ?

Comment: I am not aware that there any zipped soruce, but you can use svn client and get source

Answer (score 1):

As of now [Apache link](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/download.html) does not work

I got the dlls from [NuGet site](http://nuget.org/packages/Lucene.net)

You can try [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/lucene.net) too

Answer (score 0):

You need to build it yourself, or find someone else that has built the source. If you have visual studio installed it's as easy as opening the solution and just building it, apart from getting an external reference to a Zip-library (SharpZipLib) and include it in the project.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache Lucene.Net download page has both source and binary available [here](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/download.html).

Nuget has the binaries available [here](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Lucene). The package names are "Lucene" and "Lucene.Contrib".